# Multiple pages on view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to achieve view pager like below

[image: viewpager]

As you see the page is scaling when ,

i know we can achieve this by information but how and am new to android.
The actual effect i want to get is as below

[image]

How can i achieve this effect? i have no idea how to start please help,

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you seem to have gotten your solution there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: @NileshRathod am trying to achieve on diffrent methord, just because of the screen shot dont say both same, both are diffrent i just wanna know how to make to view as view pager insted of recylerview, if you have any ideas please share it will be helpful, please understand my questions before mark as duplicate, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this logic you can definitely get that you want

**code implementation**

```
List<Fragment> fragments = buildFragments();
ArrayList<String> categories = {"1", "2", "3", ..., "n"};
mPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPageAdapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, categories);
mPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);

//Add a new Fragment to the list with bundle
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("position", i);
String title = "asd";
mPageAdapter.add(MyFragment.class, title, b);
mPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**MyFragmentPageAdapter.java**

```
public class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public static int pos = 0;

private List<Fragment> myFragments;
private ArrayList<String> categories;
private Context context;

public MyFragmentPageAdapter(Context c, FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> myFrags, ArrayList<String> cats) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    myFragments = myFrags;
    this.categories = cats;
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return myFragments.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return myFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    setPos(position);
    return categories.get(position);
}

public static int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public void add(Class<Fragment> c, String title, Bundle b) {
    myFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(context,c.getName(),b));
    categories.add(title);
}

public static void setPos(int pos) {
    MyFragmentPageAdapter.pos = pos;
}
}
```

**Fragments list builder**

```
private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> buildFragments() {
        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
        for(int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", i);
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,MyPagerFragment.class.getName(),b));
        }

        return fragments;
}
```

Comment: but this wont give an effect like above, i think its with page transform funtion

Comment: it's for dynamic page in pageview